# Error starting up React Native packager "Cannot find module metro-bundler"

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg

I have a simple React Native project that works fine on the original machine I created it on, but when I clone the git repo on another machine and try to run the iOS project, I get this error when starting the packager:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'metro-bundler/build/lib/formatBanner'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/checkNodeVersion.js:12:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

The project is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/lyahdav/RNViewSnapshotExample). I purposely didn't git ignore the `node_modules` folder because this project has some slight modifications to React Native itself. It seems if I delete `node_modules` and `yarn install` it resolves the issue but I'd like to have the GitHub repo in a state where you can clone and you don't need to run anything to set up dependencies.

Comment: You can fork react-native and manage your changes in a repo. Just add the repo url in your package.json https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository